Callback function triggers several times
I'm trying to implement this logic:
User presses the button -> button calls "api/login" -> api/login constructs the Spotify authorization URL and redirects user to Spotify permission window -> then Spotify redirects to a callback page with Spotify query params -> after this I'm sending the code to my auth API and redirect back to my page.
But for some reasons callback triggers 3 times, while other pieces running only once.
Button Function
  const handler = (name) => {
    console.log("runnig"); 
    if (name === "Your account") {
      window.location.replace("/api/login");
    }
  };


login
export async function GET() {
  let url =
    "https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?" +
    querystring.stringify({
      response_type: "code",
      client_id: process.env.CLIENT_ID, 
      scope: "",
      redirect_uri: process.env.REDIRECT_URI, 
      state: state, 
    });
  return NextResponse.redirect(url);
}


Callback
export default function Callback() {
// 3x running with reactStrict 2x running without 

  useEffect(() => {
// 2x running with reactStrict 1x runnig without 
    processQuery();
  }, []);

  return <div>Processing...</div>;
}
const processQuery = async () => {
  const querySearch = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  await sendQuery(querySearch);
  window.location.href =
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL + window.location.search;
};

I tried to disable reactStrict and now it triggers 2 times instead of one but my logic wrapped in useEffect so its working fine (running only once). If something is completely wrong and uncommon please tell me.

Hard to say what's happening with the incomplete [mcve]. Based on the comments in the code this sounds like completely normal and expected behavior when using the React.StrictMode component. Outside that, I don't really understand what the handler issue is. Please [edit] to clarify the problem and include a complete and relevant [mcve].

@DrewReese, as I understand it, strict mode causes the component to re-render one extra time, but in my case, the code runs 3 times when strict mode is enabled. When I disable strict mode, I expect it to run just once instead of twice, but instead, my handler starts running twice. I can share a screenshot, though I doubt it would add much clarity. I think I've already provided the full logic cycle, and I'm unsure what additional information would be helpful.

A complete [mcve] would show how these 3 snippets relate to each other. That's what is missing. Right now it looks like 3 unrelated chunks of code and nothing anyone could use to reproduce anything. Along with a complete code example in the post you could try also creating a running Codesandbox demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live.

Hmm, it could be that window.location.href = ... the effect triggers that reloads the page and also triggers additional renders because the app remounted. This is just a guess because, again, we don't have a good picture what your code is doing really.

@DrewReese can spotify authorize block my redirection if im using a codesandbox?
